# Plugin ou Configuração para Intellij IDEA utilizando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plugin, intellij-idea, configuração

Utilizo o intellij idea community e ao escrever algum código em javascript a IDE não deixa o nome das funções coloridas, para facilitar a interpretação do código. Alguém conhece algum plugin ou configuração que possa me ajudar com isso. Já utilizo o Rainbow Brackets, mas não funciona com javascript.
Vou deixer um exemplo de como fica pra vocês verem no código.

[intellij idea community vejam a tag script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psuUm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript não é suportado na versão community por padrão, apenas na Ultimate (versão paga). Mas é possível destacar a sua sintaxe usando um plugin.

O plugin [Text Mate Bundes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7221-textmate-bundles) ajuda a destacar o texto do Javascript.

Como instalar o TextMate Bundles com pacotes de linguagem (Javascript):

1. Instale e habilite o plugin TextMate no IntelliJ;
2. Baixe os pacotes de idiomas específicos e descompacte-os em algum lugar onde você os encontre;
3. Abra a caixa de diálogo Configurações/Preferências, acesse o Editor e selecione "TextMate Bundles";
4. Clique no "+" no lado direito e escolha o pacote desejado (Javascript, do item 2) no seu disco rígido. Então deverá aparecer na lista de "bundles" (pacotes) reconhecidos.
5. Podem aparecer conflitos de extensão: clique em "Mostrar detalhes". Se você quiser usar o novo destaque de sintaxe, clique em "cancelar registro do tipo de arquivo nativo".

Espero que ajude! :)

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).